# Can one remotely access an IPython Notebook without using inline plotting?

Tags: matplotlib, x11, ipython

I'd like to connect to an IPython notebook on a remote computer (either via an ssh-tunnel or via https) and have the ipython notebook open a matplotlib plot in a new window (versus 'inline').

Is this possible?

When I attempt to plot without the 'inline' backend, the notebook kernal reports ' : cannot connect to X server ', and crashes.

X11 server is running on the client computer, and I enabled X11 forwarding using the -Y option when creating the ssh-tunnel.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You need to enable X11 forwarding on the remote computer too (with sshd options).

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this option is enabled, i.e I can use X11 to open windows for emacs,gimp,etc... but somehow the ipython kernel running notebook is unable to.

Comment: Firstly, you said "using the -Y option" : it should be `-X`. Now, I've been able to do this from one of my Ubuntu computers (though it was a little unstable.. tended to snap my adsl connection). From my other box (with direct internet), the ipython kernels crash with "cannot connect to X server" if I try to `show()` a plot. As yet, I've not worked out why...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is, at least via ssh port tunneling.

(NOTE: the examples blow were done on Ubuntu 12.04, but the same principle should work for other platforms)

I was having similar problems and found that if I run the IPython notebook from within the port- and X-forwarding ssh session (ie: the one that sets up the port and X forwarding), it works. Clunky and annoying, but it works. For example:

```
at-home:~$ ssh -X -L 8889:localhost:8888 my.server
... login message from my.server
my.server:$ cd /folder/containing/my/notebooks
my.server:$ ipython notebook
[NotebookApp] .... lots of info about the IPython notebook server including
[NotebookApp] The IPython notebook is running at 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/'
```

Note that I've forwarded port 8889 - this means I use `http://localhost:8889/` in a browser on my `at-home` machine. For me, this works nicely with the Qt4Agg backend.

I suspect that it will also work for accessing notebooks over https if you run the IPython notebook server in this way (ie: from within an `ssh -X` session). Note that the plots will appear on the machine from which the X session was forwarded. If someone runs a notebook in a browser on another machine, this could be a bit strange!

It may be possible to tell a running IPython notebook server how to find the X server forwarded by some new ssh session, but I'm not sure how (knowledgeable edits welcome!).

Comment: +1 ! thanks, this solved my problem of "port forwarding" a remote ipython notebook right away